# Cannot locate cause of nullpointer when using .getWidth()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

I have a hard time locating why I am returned a nullpointer on this piece of code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Move {

  private static final int DIAMETER = 30;

  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int x_1 = 1;
  int y_1 = 1;


  private GameStart game;

  public void Ball(GameStart game) {
    this.game = game;
  }

  void moveBall() {
    if (x + x_1 < 0) {
        x_1 = 1;
    }

    if (x + x_1 > game.getWidth() - DIAMETER) {
        x_1 = -1;
    }

    if (y + y_1 < 0) {
        y_1 = 1;
    }

    if (y + y_1 > game.getHeight() - DIAMETER) {
        game.gameOver();
    }

    if (collision()) {
        y_1 = -1;
        y = game.racquet.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
    }

    x = x + x_1;
    y = y + y_1;
  }

  private boolean collision() {
    return game.racquet.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
  }

  public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
  }

  public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
  }

}
```

And the GameStart class is here:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameStart extends JPanel {

  Move move_ball = new Move();
  Racquet racquet = new Racquet(this);

  public GameStart() {

    addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {          
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            racquet.keyReleased(e);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            racquet.keyPressed(e);
        }

    });

    setFocusable(true);

  }

  private void move() {
    move_ball.moveBall();
    racquet.move();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    move_ball.paint(graphics);
    racquet.paint(graphics);
  }

  public void gameOver() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Spil slut", "Du tabte", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    System.exit(ABORT);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Matematikken");
    GameStart game = new GameStart();
    mainWindow.add(game);
    mainWindow.setSize(300, 400);
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {

        game.move();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);

    }

  }

}
```

I am getting a nullpointer on the line `if (x + x_1 > game.getWidth() - DIAMETER) {`. I am using `.getWidth()` in the samme manner in another class and it Works fine - but for some reason it wont in this. I've tried printing the result but that is just another nullpointer. I know i am missing something but I cannot locate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not calling

```
public void Ball(GameStart game) {
    this.game = game;
}
```

That's why in your `Move` class, `GameStart` is still null.

Comment: I just tried removing `this.game = game` as another post with another NPE suggested but no luck. Using `this.game.getWidth()` returns NPE aswell. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Why do you have that method? What's `Ball`? Is it a typo from copy-pasting? I think Seelenvirtouse's hunch is correct.

Comment: I am not directly copy-pasting - but following: http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game6.html  
I can see that I am not calling the Ball constructor. That should be the issue right?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and not just pasting a working example! cheers man!

Comment: Yes that is the issue, replace `Ball` with `Move` and declare `Move move_ball = new Move(this);`. For a better explanation, see @Seelenvirtuose's answer.

Comment: Glad to help someone who is willing to learn and not just copy code :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you wanted that method

```
public void Ball(GameStart game) { this.game = game; }
```

to actually be a constructor:

```
public Move(GameStart game) { this.game = game; }
```

And then, you must use this constructor (as there is no no-arg constructor anymore) when instantiating a `Move`:

```
Move move_ball = new Move(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not yet set the member variable `game` of the instance `move_ball` of the type `Move` to a value so it is `null` and therefore throws a NullPointerException.

You'll want to instantiate this member variable, for example by calling `move_ball.Ball(<some Game instance>)`.

Also, please don't let methods which are not constructors start with a capital and please use camelCase throughout instead of switching between name formatting. It makes your code hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You do not pass `GameStart` to `Move` via your `Ball` method. It is very misleading name. It should be `setGame` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a constructor for the Move class, which takes the game as a parameter, and store that parameter in a variable within the class.

Example:

```
Public Move(GameStart mygame){
    game = mygame;
}
```

This should allow you to use the methods of the game from which you are creating the move.  It will basically replace the "Ball" method you have.